# Python import using dot notation doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3, importerror, python-import

I recently installed a library in Python 3.3.2. I tried to import a module from it like this: `import cx_Freeze.freezer`. However, cx_Freeze.freezer is not defined as I would have expected, as shown in IDLE:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> import cx_Freeze.freezer
>>> cx_Freeze.freezer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    cx_Freeze.freezer
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'freezer'
>>>
```

The same thing happens in the command line. I think I am misunderstanding what happens when you use import with dot notation; what name does the module get assigned to?

In order to fix this seeming problem, I tried `import cx_Freeze.freezer as f` after restarting the shell, but that gave the same error as before. Can someone please explain why these import statements aren't giving me access to the module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`cx_Freeze/__init__.py`](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/src/173bceaed4c34e1ec103a94a75f735b31317a4cb/cx_Freeze/__init__.py?at=default) has the following contents:

```
version = "5.0"

import sys
from cx_Freeze.dist import *
if sys.platform == "win32":
    from cx_Freeze.windist import *
elif sys.platform == "darwin":
    from cx_Freeze.macdist import *
from cx_Freeze.finder import *
from cx_Freeze.freezer import *
from cx_Freeze.main import *

del dist
del finder
del freezer
```

The parts important to this question are `from cx_Freeze.freezer import *` and `del freezer`. The first of those lines imports everything listed in `cx_Freeze.freezer.__all__` directly into the `cx_Freeze` package, and the second line makes `cx_Freeze.freezer` not available directly. Thus, you should probably just use `cx_Freeze`; it contains all the parts of `cx_Freeze.freezer` designed for external use. If you need `cx_Freeze.freezer`, perhaps to use some of the private functionality, you can find it in `sys.modules`:

```
import sys
freezer = sys.modules['cx_Freeze.freezer']
```

Comment: This is cool; thank you for the helpful answer. However, I was hoping for an answer that would not be particular to `cx_Freeze`, but would explain what's going on inside `import`. Are the errors I demonstrated in my question a result of the code you're showing here? I thought that importing `cx_Freeze.freezer` directly would bypass the `__init__` file; is this not the case?

Comment: @Matthew: A package must always be initialized by running its `__init__` file before its contents may be imported. `del freezer` is the part that breaks the use of `cx_Freeze.freezer`; it removes the `freezer` name from the package's namespace.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question. Please consider editing that explanation into your original answer so it is clear to future viewers.